# Supermarket Billing System

Tags: python, billing, price

I'm a newbie at Python and was working on a Supermarket Billing system.
So far, I got this:

```
# Supermarket Billing
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
while True:
    item = input('Item: ')
    amount = input('Amount: ')
    a = int(amount)
    price = input('Price: ')
    b = int(price)
    c += a * b
    next_item = input('Is there another item? ')
    if next_item != 'Yes':
        print('Please choose between Yes or No')
    if next_item == 'No':
        break
print('Total: ', c)
```

It works all fine. But I wanna omit the price. Like if the user types in 'Mango' it should automatically get the price from the code and multiple the amount with the price to get a total.

i tried before with:

```
if item == 'Mango'
final_price_mango = a * 23.0 #Let's say price is 23.0
```

So for every item i would have to give the price of the item in different block of code making the code lengthy. Is there no generic way?
Say, putting the prices in a list

```
[23.0, 43.02, 5.6, 100.75]
```

And so automatically it'll be like Mango's price is 23.0, Flour is 43.02 and calculate accordingly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into [dictionaries](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-tutorial) and also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: @roganjosh I'll try with that once.

Answer (score 0):

## make an array of prices.

Declare the prices.
So your output will be:enter the fruit name. 
As soon as you enter the fruit name, it will take the address of it and multiply it by the fixed price.

## declaration code

```
prices = { "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
```

Declare the prices and then call it by a function.